# How can I use the doc ID in a calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, 2019

The document ID is this: `EY3P5SDA5APP-512271551-6`

and I would like to isolate the last digit (here 6) using a formula. I tried this formula:

```
=RIGHT([Valeur d’ID de document],LEN([Valeur d’ID de document])-INT(FIND("-",[Valeur d’ID de document])))
```

but then it returns this: `512271551-6`

We are using Sharepoint 2019 on-premises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the last one digit from the document ID, you can simply use:

```
=RIGHT([Valeur d’ID de document],1)
```

---

If you want to get the number after second `-` in document ID, you can try using this formula:

```
=RIGHT([Valeur d’ID de document],LEN([Valeur d’ID de document])-FIND("-",[Valeur d’ID de document],FIND("-",[Valeur d’ID de document])+1))
```

**Reference**: [Find last occurrence of a character in SharePoint Calculated Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969654/find-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-sharepoint-calculated-column)

---

**Documentation**: [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd option is exactly what I was looking for.